# Python return list when query has no result

Tags: python, parameters

I am a newbie to Python, using Python 2.7. I am passing in a list of strings from the command line and running two different queries using that list of strings. The list contains 4 IDs which are valid and which are returned in the first query. The last two IDs are invalid. I need to print both of the results to a file.

I am running the query as:

```sh
python empdetails.py -i "'ADM10','TMC34','LAB57','WSD44','GM22','AD32'" -o (file_location)
```

```py
import os
import sys,getopt
from impala.dbapi import connect

def main(argv):

    input = ''
    output = ''
    try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["input=","output"])
    except getopt.GetOptError:
      print 'Usage append.py -i <input> -o <output>'
      sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print 'Usage append.py -i <input> -o <output>'
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--input"):
         input = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--output"):
         output = arg
         print input


    conn = connect(host='hostname', port=port_number, auth_mechanism='GSSAPI', kerberos_service_name='impala', use_ssl=True)

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    sql = ('select empcode from empinfo where empcode in (select ecode from emptrav_det where ecode in({}))'.format(input))
    cursor.execute (sql)
    duplicate = cursor.fetchall()

    sql =('select ecode from emptrav_det where exp_c in({})'.format(input))
    print sql
    cursor.execute (sql)
    new = cursor.fetchall()
    if duplicate !=0:
       with open('output', 'a') as f:
          for emp in duplicate:
              f.write(str(emp[0]) + " " + ("Traveled\n"))

    if new ==0:
       with open('output', 'a') as f:
          for emp in new:
              f.write(str(emp[0]) + " " + ("Invalid ID\n"))

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if new == 0:
   with open('output', 'a') as f:
      for emp in new:
          f.write(str(emp[0]) + " " + ("Invalid ID\n"))
```

First of all, `new` will be an empty `list` or `tuple`. To check for that, you cannot do `if new == 0`.. You have to do something like:

```
if not new:
```

The second problem is your logic:

You are iterating over `new` inside a block that checks for `if new == 0`. How do you expect that to work? (too much copy-paste from the code above I guess). Do this instead:

```
if not new:
   with open('output', 'a') as f:
      f.write("Invalid ID\n")
```

Comment: Tried this way, but do not get the output for Invalid, also I would need to print the IDs which are invalid

Comment: then write `input` to your file. The point is to understand the logic and what you are doing wrong. `input` is a bad variable name btw; it shadows a Python built-in